# Loop to append multiple lists into dataframe python

Tags: python-3.x, loops, pandas

I have to `requests.get()` two urls from yahoo utilizing `YQL` that returns a `json` object. I'm getting back a `json` objects that I store into a `list()`. Then I'm looping to parse the data and creating a dic to then create a pandas data frame. Happened that only one list is getting appended to the data frame. Seems like in the last iteration, the 2nd list overwrites the first list. At this point, I can't figure out how to iterate on the list to `append()` both elements of the list. Here is my code...

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


urls = ['https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22DIA%22%2C%22SPY%22%2C%22IWN%22)%20and%20startDate%20%3D%20%222015-01-01%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%20%222015-10-31%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=',
        'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22DIA%22%2C%22SPY%22%2C%22IWN%22)%20and%20startDate%20%3D%20%222015-11-01%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%20%222016-08-31%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=']


for url in urls:
    data = requests.get(url)
    data_json = data.json()

    quote_list = []
    for quote in data_json['query']['results']['quote']:
        quote_dic = {'symbol': quote['Symbol'],
                 'date': quote['Date'],
                 'volume': quote['Volume'],
                 'low': quote['Low'],
                 'high': quote['High'],
                 'open': quote['Open'],
                 'close': quote['Close'],
                 'adj_close': quote['Adj_Close']}

        quote_list.append(quote_dic)

    quote_df = pd.DataFrame(quote_list)

quote_df.to_csv('stocks.csv')
```

I need to be able to append the entire `list()` into the data frame. What would be the fix for this code?

Comment: Why store the json in a list? json is essentially a dictionary natively and can be loaded into a dictionary with no parsing or translation.

Comment: Can I append the `json` straight to the data frame?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Pandas dataframes however, according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31695108/how-to-append-a-dictionary-to-a-pandas-dataframe it looks pretty simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a list of dataframes, and concat them at the end of the loop:

```
df_list = []
for url in urls:
    data = requests.get(url)
    data_json = data.json()

    df = pd.DataFrame(data_json['query']['results']['quote'])
    df_list.append(df)

quote_df = pd.concat(df_list)
quote_df.to_csv('stocks.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this solution?

```
import urllib
import re
import json

symbolslist = open("C:/Users/your_path_here/Desktop/stock_symbols.txt").read()
symbolslist = symbolslist.split("\n")

for symbol in symbolslist:
    myfile = open("C:/Users/your_path_here/Desktop/" +symbol +".txt", "w+")
    myfile.close()

    htmltext = urllib.urlopen("http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/chart/data/1D/"+ symbol+ ":US")
    data = json.load(htmltext)
    datapoints = data["data_values"]

    myfile = open("C:/Users/rshuell001/Desktop/symbols/" +symbol +".txt", "a")
    for point in datapoints:
        myfile.write(str(symbol+","+str(point[0])+","+str(point[1])+"\n"))
    myfile.close()
```

In this file "C:/Users/your_path_here/Desktop/symbols/amex.txt"
you have the following tickers

```
ibm
sbux
msft
```

Comment: The above solution worked well since I'm connecting to yahoo api and inserting to postgresql without saving data to hard drive. I'm having an issue though,which is in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40519046/insert-dataframe-into-postgresql-sqlalchemy-with-idx-autoincrement)