# Insert dataframe into postgresql sqlalchemy with idx autoincrement

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm `requests.get()` to get some json. After that, I want to insert the data into postgresql. Something very interesting is happening, if I use the `df.to_sql(index=False)`, the data gets appended into postgresql with no problem, but the Id in postgresql is not creating the autoincrement value; the column is totally empty. If I eliminate the parameter in `df.to_sql()` then I get the following error... `IntegrityError: (psycopg2.IntegrityError) duplicate key value violates unique constraint`. Here is my code...

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy

urls = ['https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20%3D%20%22DIA%22%20and%20startDate%20%3D%20%222015-01-01%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%20%222015-12-31%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=',
    'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20%3D%20%22DIA%22%20and%20startDate%20%3D%20%222016-01-01%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%20%222016-11-08%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=',
    'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20%3D%20%22SPY%22%20and%20startDate%20%3D%20%222015-01-01%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%20%222015-12-31%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=',
    'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20%3D%20%22SPY%22%20and%20startDate%20%3D%20%222016-01-01%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%20%222016-11-08%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=',
    'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20%3D%20%22IWN%22%20and%20startDate%20%3D%20%222015-01-01%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%20%222015-12-31%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=',
    'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20%3D%20%22IWN%22%20and%20startDate%20%3D%20%222016-01-01%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%20%222016-11-08%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=']
df_list = []
for url in urls:
    data = requests.get(url)
    data_json = data.json()
    df = pd.DataFrame(data_json['query']['results']['quote'])
    df_list.append(df)


quote_df = pd.concat(df_list)
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql://postgres:wpc,.2016@localhost:5432/stocks')
quote_df.to_sql('quotes', engine, if_exists='append')
```

I would like to insert the `df` into postgresql with the postgresql autoincrement index. 
How can I fix my code to do so.

#### Question Update 10NOV2016 1900

I add the following code to fix the indexing in the data frame...

```
quote_df = pd.concat(df_list)
quote_df.index.name = 'Index'
quote_df = quote_df.reset_index()
quote_df['Index'] = quote_df.index

engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:wpc,.2016@localhost:5432/stocks')
```

quote_df.to_sql('quotes', engine, if_exists = 'append', index=False)
    engine.dispose()

Now I'm having the following error when appending to postgresql...

```
ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column "Index" of relation "quotes" does not exist LINE 1: INSERT INTO quotes ("Index", "Adj_Close", "Close", "Date", "...
```

The column does exists in the database.

Comment: can you post `create table ...` statement for your PostgreSQL table?

Comment: I create the table in pgadmin4. The column names are the same as the json object.

Answer (score 0):

One way (among many) to do this would be:

to fetch maximum `Id` and store it to a variable (let's call it `max_id`):

```
select max(Id) from quotes;
```

now we can do this:

Original DF:

```
In [55]: quote_df
Out[55]:
      Adj_Close       Close        Date        High         Low        Open Symbol   Volume
0    170.572764  173.990005  2015-12-31  175.649994  173.970001  175.089996    DIA  5773400
1    172.347213  175.800003  2015-12-30  176.720001  175.619995  176.570007    DIA  2910000
2     173.50403  176.979996  2015-12-29      177.25      176.00  176.190002    DIA  6145700
..          ...         ...         ...         ...         ...         ...    ...      ...
213   88.252244   89.480003  2016-01-06   90.099998   89.080002   89.279999    IWN  1570400
214   89.297697   90.540001  2016-01-05   90.620003       89.75   90.410004    IWN  2053100
215   88.893319   90.129997  2016-01-04   90.730003   89.360001   90.550003    IWN  2540600

[1404 rows x 8 columns]
```

now we can increase index by `max_id`:

```
In [56]: max_id = 123456    # <-- you don't need this line... 

In [57]: quote_df.index += max_id
```

and set index as `Id` column:

```
In [58]: quote_df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'Id'})
Out[58]:
          Id   Adj_Close       Close        Date        High         Low        Open Symbol   Volume
0     123456  170.572764  173.990005  2015-12-31  175.649994  173.970001  175.089996    DIA  5773400
1     123457  172.347213  175.800003  2015-12-30  176.720001  175.619995  176.570007    DIA  2910000
2     123458   173.50403  176.979996  2015-12-29      177.25      176.00  176.190002    DIA  6145700
...      ...         ...         ...         ...         ...         ...         ...    ...      ...
1401  123669   88.252244   89.480003  2016-01-06   90.099998   89.080002   89.279999    IWN  1570400
1402  123670   89.297697   90.540001  2016-01-05   90.620003       89.75   90.410004    IWN  2053100
1403  123671   88.893319   90.129997  2016-01-04   90.730003   89.360001   90.550003    IWN  2540600

[1404 rows x 9 columns]
```

Now it should be possible to write this DF to PostgreSQL specifying (`index=False`)

Comment: I can't fetch `max(Id)` because at this moment the table is empty; no rows whatsoever. This dataframe will be the first data that I'm going to insert in postgresql.

Comment: @Gilbert, what does `print(max_id)` after you fetched it from the empty table?

Comment: Jupyter is returning an error with `select max(Id) from quotes`. Is this the complete line of code or this is sudo code that I have to include in a `sqlalchamy` statement?

Comment: @Gilbert, that's a SQL that must be executed and fetched using SQLAlchemy or Psycopg2 ...

Comment: `max_id` is returning a sqlalchemy object; `<sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy object at #######>` I'm suppouse is returning that object because the table is empty.

Comment: With these lines of code, I fixed the index problem in the data frame... `quote_df.index.name = 'Index'
quote_df = quote_df.reset_index()
quote_df['Index'] = quote_df.index`. Now I get the following error appending to the database... `ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column "Index" of relation "quotes" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO quotes ("Index", "Adj_Close", "Close", "Date", "...` The column does exists  in the database.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer to my own question 11NOV2016 1112

I figure out that after `df.reset_index()`, I can delete the extra column pandas create and the original index column stays reset. Now if I execute the code without `index=False`, sqlalchemy will insert the index into postgres. Here is the code that solve my problem...

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

urls = ['https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20%3D%20%22DIA%22%20and%20startDate%20%3D%20%222015-01-01%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%20%222015-12-31%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=',
    'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20%3D%20%22DIA%22%20and%20startDate%20%3D%20%222016-01-01%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%20%222016-11-11%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=',
    'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20%3D%20%22SPY%22%20and%20startDate%20%3D%20%222015-01-01%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%20%222015-12-31%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=',
    'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20%3D%20%22SPY%22%20and%20startDate%20%3D%20%222016-01-01%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%20%222016-11-11%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=',
    'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20%3D%20%22IWN%22%20and%20startDate%20%3D%20%222015-01-01%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%20%222015-12-31%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=',
    'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20%3D%20%22IWN%22%20and%20startDate%20%3D%20%222016-01-01%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%20%222016-11-11%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=']

df_list = []
for url in urls:
    data = requests.get(url)
    data_json = data.json()
    df = pd.DataFrame(data_json['query']['results']['quote'])
    df_list.append(df)

quote_df = pd.concat(df_list)
quote_df = quote_df.reset_index()
quote_df = quote_df.drop('index', 1)


engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:wpc,.2016@localhost:5432/stocks')
quote_df.to_sql('quotes', engine, if_exists='append')
```